# Android NSD Manager Service Registartion

Tags: android, service-discovery, nsdmanager

I am using NSD Manager in android app to register a service .
But service registration is happening successfully sometimes and sometimes it doesnt happen even for minutes. For the times it doesn't successfully register the service the onRegistrationFailed callback is also not called, so there is no way to debug as to why service registration is not happening.  There is no particular pattern that i am able to identify as to when service registration is not happening.